# Is there a simple template for invoices that Software Consultants can issue?

Tags: templates

This is for individual consultants to issue to paying-party for consulting services.

In case, this is NOT the forum please let me know which **StackExchange** site this question should move to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have already tried this, but Microsoft Word has a bunch of built in Invoice templates. If they aren't showing up for you, you can visit office online to download a few directly from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks! But is that  - Invoice with hours and rate -  sufficient or ... are there some specific legal headers required for individual consultants?

Comment: @Maximus No problem! I'm not sure if there are any specific required headers for individual consultants, but I'm sure if you check out the rules and regulations of owning/operating an LLC or consulting firm in your residence, that they would state somewhere in the regulations of what you should place in the header/footer (if anything).